# What to update to keep the server secured?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, configuration, centos6

I've been asked to specify which updates are needed to update our server and  have it secured - problem is I'm not an expert on this.

I know that we've very old software. For my work I need PHP 7.2 and mySQL 5.5+, but don't know what else to check. I know we're running on:

- Centos 6.5
- Linux 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
- Apache/2.2.15

Do any of these things need to be updated? To which version?
Do we need to check anything else?
Cheers.

Comment: Update all packages regularly. It’s best to use the Cents repo which also picks the latest update automatically. And also plan to switch to 7 soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step: Update to CentOS 6.10 plus any subsequent updated packages.  v6.5 is really old now (5+ years...). This should also take care of the Kernel and any system services like Apache and MySQL if you used the default packages.

If you have installed PHP7 or other stuff via 3rd party means, make sure this is updated as well.

Comment: And note that C6 is only supported for about another year and a half; start planning your migration now.

Comment: 2020 is less then 1.5 years from now. Waaah :(

Comment: @Sven thanks for the reply. I've not installed PHP7 yet, we're still on 5.x. It's used as a server for a website, do you know anything else to be checked?

Comment: Another question: CentOS 6.10 or 7+? Is it a lot mor difficult to go to 7+?

Comment: If all you run is a web site, then it's a fairly straightforward upgrade.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Upgrading from PHP5 - 7 is not always a straightforward upgrade. There are major issues with some stuff, minor issues with some other stuff, and no issues at all for lots. At minimum upgrading php on this setup will require at least a bit of Apache reconfig.

Comment: @RobbieCrash The OP clearly stated that he needs PHP 7.2 for his app. So I expect he will have absolutely no backward compatibility issues...

Comment: @MichaelHampton in their comment it states they're still on 5.x, so while they eventually will not have any backwards compatibility issues, the upgrade may not be super straightforward.

Comment: @RobbieCrash I've a wordpress blog with some basic plugins and a xenforo forum. Do you think I'll face any particular problem with the upgrade to PHP 7.2?

Comment: @testermaster: Test it. Spin up a VM with that environment and then update it to your desired state and see if everything continues to work as expected...

Comment: @testmaster in addition to what Sven's comment, there are WordPress plugins that will test your PHP to see what, if any, changes you'll need to make. Aside from what's required there, you'll need to update your Apache configuration to point to the new version. Other than those two things it should be very simple.

Comment: Regarding FTP & SSL, is there any necessary update? Thanks for your help! :)